# XUbuntu Shared Folder In VMware

Tags: directory

How do I share folders between my Windows partition and Xubuntu 12.04 installed in VMware?

Answer (score 1):

So far NTFS is the only reliable method to do this. I've added this line in my `/etc/fstab` to do this with my laptop:

```
/dev/sda5 /mnt/share ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

But first you'll probably want to do the following before adding the line:

- Locate the */dev name* for your Windows partition. Mine is /dev/sda5.
- Create a mount directory: `mkdir /mnt/<dir_name>`
- Mount the partition to your mount directory: 
   `mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda5 /mnt/<dir_name>`

You can check your mount by issuing:

```
df -kh
```

You should see an output like this:

```
/dev/sda5       220G   56G  165G  26% /mnt/share
```

At this point, go ahead and go to the directory and try writing to the file system with something like:

```
touch test.txt
```

If this is successful, then you should be able to add this line to your /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/sda5 /mnt/share ntfs-3g defaults 0 0
```

Save it and reboot. It should mount by default on a full restart.

Hope this is helpful.